# Get user profile info using Google Contacts access token

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I trying to get the user profile info especially email Id through Google  Contacts access token.
I have read some other posts and found out that we can get the profile info by using this URL through GET call.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=XXX
```

but I get that response as

```
{
 "azp": "client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "aud": "client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "scope": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds",
 "exp": "1454279686",
 "expires_in": "3586",
 "access_type": "offline"
}
```

How do I get the email id of the user with the google contacts access token?

Comment: I don't think totkeninfo always returns an email. unless its been authenticated with email or profile scopes.   It should be returning userid which is Googles internal userid.

Comment: Is there any other way that I can get the user email Id using the access token.

Answer (score 0):

As @daimto mentioned, you'll need to be authenticated (thru oAuth2.0) to use the Contacts API. Fortunately, its [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?hl=en) details how you can start.

However, to [retrieve Contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?hl=en#retrieving_all_contacts), you'll have to know the `email address` since its the parameter you'll be passing to retrieve the Contact information (depends on the projection (`thin`, `property-*Key*`, `full`)

Comment: yes, we'll only be authenticated thru OAuth 2.0, at this time we don't have the email-Id of the user. We can retrieve the contacts by using https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full url, but here @adjuremods we can mention "default" in the place of {userEmail} as we also send the Authorization header with access_token.
We get the name and email of the user in the above url call along with 25 contacts in the response. My concern is, does google provide email-id information with the access_token.

Comment: small typo in the above comment, url is - google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full